# Java - Filter Returning Null Value

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, filter, filtering

I am trying to filter list but it returning null value for every search. I tried every possible ways but nothing happened. please help me on this

```
public class IssuerCreditDetailsUpdate implements ItemProcessor<Isin_Master, Issuer_credit_rating_details> {

    protected final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(this.getClass().getName());
    static ArrayList<Credit_rating_details> Credit = new ArrayList<Credit_rating_details>();
    private String validCreditRating = null;

    @Override
    public Issuer_credit_rating_details process(Isin_Master item) throws Exception {
        Issuer_credit_rating_details row = new Issuer_credit_rating_details();
        if(isCreditRatingValid(item.getIssuer_Id())!= null) {   
                        row.setIssuer_id(item.getIssuer_Id());
            row.setName_of_issuer(item.getIssuerName());

            return row;
        }

        return null;
    }

    private String isCreditRatingValid(String issuerid) {
        System.out.println(Credit.stream().filter(i-> i.getIssuer_id().contains(issuerid)).collect(Collectors.toList()));
        List<Credit_rating_details> result = Credit.stream().filter(i-> i.getIssuer_id().contains(issuerid)).collect(Collectors.toList());
        if(!result.isEmpty() ) {

            validCreditRating = result.get(0).getCredit_rating();
            return result.get(0).getCredit_rating();
        }else {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `Credit` is empty always, no?

Comment: @user7294900  - no, jpa annotation set in POJO, it connected with table

Comment: Can you provide the `Issuer_id` values from your `ArrayList` and the value of `issuerid` that is passed to the `isCreditRatingValid` method?

Comment: Could you share the values of the arraylist and issuer_id?

Answer (score 0):

Possibly, `i-> i.getIssuer_id().contains(issuerid)` is not matching the way you are expecting. 
What is the type returned by Credit_rating_details.getIssuer_id()? Is it also a String? 
Is it possible that the input issuerid and the Credit_rating_details issuer_id are in different cases?
Try `i-> i.getIssuer_id().equalsIgnoreCase(issuerid)` to see if you get a different result.